# Where to find a comprehensive list of proto-cuneiform Sumerian glyphs?

Tags: language, writing, mesopotamia, sumer

I'm looking for representations and meanings of the logographs of the Uruk period (3500–3000 BC), such as those on the [Kish tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kish_tablet). I've only been able to find a few examples, but [over 1000](https://www.sumerian.org/sumerlex.htm) are known. The only relevant work I've seen referenced is Falkenstein (1936), which I can't find anywhere.

Comment: Falkenstein's book, [Archaische Texte aus Uruk](https://cdli.ucla.edu/tools/SignLists/ATU1.pdf) is available as a pdf file from the Cuneiform Digital Library Initiative site at UCLA.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Time to learn some German.

Answer (score 6):

I have found [full list of proto-cuneiform signs (very large file [93 MB])](https://cdli.ucla.edu/tools/SignLists/protocuneiform/archsigns.html), with very detailed glyphs <s>together with their meanings</s> sadly meanings seems to be all missing. Though there is no author information.

> Also as you suggested; [A. Falkenstein, Archaische Texte aus Uruk (Archaische Texte aus
>   Uruk 1; Berlin-Leipzig
>   1936)](https://cdli.ucla.edu/tools/SignLists/ATU1.pdf)

from [Cuneiform Digital Library Initiative](http://cdli.ox.ac.uk/wiki/doku.php?id=late_uruk_period) website.

---

Another alternative, though without meanings again; [Proto-Cuneiform Signs by Ashur Cherry](https://ia600608.us.archive.org/16/items/AshurCherryProtoCuneiformSigns/Ashur_Cherry_Proto_-_Cuneiform_Signs.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! But I see all the meanings listed as `xxx`. Is that just me?

Comment: @foxpal you are right, yesterday I posted the answer just before leaving the office... I hadn't checked all meanings, assumed some were missing, hence `xxx`, but all are missing :) I couldn't find an alternative with meanings though...

Comment: @foxpal: The lists do give the _names_ of the signs (or their component parts, for composite signs) that you can use to look up their general meaning e.g. on [ePSD](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/nepsd-frame.html).